# Quick blooming flowers to grow from seed in late spring (mid/late June) that will flower in late summer/Autumn

Tags: flowers, seeds

I am new to gardening, and appear to have missed ideal planting time for the year. I want to know if I can salvage the year and get some colour. I would like to grow from seeds rather than buy plug plants.

So, is there anything I can plant now (mid/late June) that will also flower this year? I am in the UK in the midlands, so temperatures should be low/mid 20's for the coming few months.

Answer (score 3):

You mention sowing in mid/late July - its only June, but even so, it's really a bit too late, especially growing from seed in the UK - you could try nasturtiums - Tropaeolum Alaska Mixed and/or Empress of India are low growing ones which will flower until  the first frosts arrive, and the  two together make a good contrast to each other. You might get Nigella (Love in a Mist) to grow and flower if we have a long, warm autumn, that might be worth a try too, but don't delay, sow any seed within the next week. It's already too late to buy plug plants for this summer - any summer bedding still available will by now be in pots, and thus more expensive. If you really did mean to say mid to late July, then there will be nothing that will grow and flower this year from seed.

Comment: So true.  But purchasing starts, plants already grown from seed to plant in your garden should be happening.  Nurseries want to sell the plants in 3" or 4" pots so they don't have to up pot or transplant into larger pots as well as raise the price.  Gosh, Geraniums, vegetable plants,  impatiens, marigolds, asters are all needing to be transplanted or sold right now.  Don't think it is July as yet?  Grins. But growing from seed now?  Lettuce and peas!

Comment: I did mean June sorry, I will amend the question.